# How to restore stock ROM

Tags: updates, rom, ota-update, twrp, stock-rom

I am on a Samsung Galaxy S4. I bought it used, and it came with Team Win Recovery Project installed.

My simple question is - how can I remove TWRP, and restore the stock ROM?

I am not experienced with rooting or messing around with the back end of Android, so please keep that in mind when responding.

Comment: Do you find any backups in the phone which are backed up using TWRP ?

Comment: @MANI how can I search for them?

Answer (score 0):

I can not assure you the method would work or not but after browsing all over I found this satisfying post, hope it will help you too!

http://www.androidsage.com/2016/02/03/restore-samsung-galaxy-s4-to-stock-lollipop-firmware/

Try it on your own risk :)

Answer (score 0):

Well there's always a first time, so just give this a shot.
The link below will help you un-root your device and flash stock ROM as well. That way you can get your device back to fresh state.
So just follow the steps as mentioned here - 
http://rootmyandroid.org/flash-stock-rom-galaxy-s4.html/